# Office 365 Management Activity API sample

Tags: office365

I've been trying to connect to the Office 365 Management Activity API following the steps in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn707383.aspx).

I don't know what am I doing wrong but all the calls return the 401 Unauthorized code. I tried to find some code samples or more detailed walkthrough of the use of Management Activity API, but with no success.

Does anyone know where to find some code I can refer to? I already tried on OfficeDev PnP, but found nothing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a sample PowerShell script (C#) that calls the API on GitHub:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-InvestigationTooling

Also, if you post an HTTP trace of your request and response, I can help you locate the issue.

Tom

Comment: Thank you very much Tom! The sample works fine and now I see I was doing wrong the authentication flow. I guess I will be able to translate the Powershell script into a Web App now.